# Efficient search of substrings in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to search in a User collection for a document containing a given username while the user is typing in the username. For example:

Database:

```
happyuser
happyuser2
happy_user
userhappy
```

User types in "hap", all usernames should be found, since "hap" is included in all of them. When I do the following, only results are found, when the full username is provided and non of the results is found for the query "hap":

```
User.find(
    {
        $text: {
            $search: "hap",
            $diacriticSensitive: true
        }
    },
    {
        score: {
            $meta: "textScore"
        }
    }, function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        next(err);
        return;
    }

    return res.json(results);
});
```

I only get results, when I search by providing a regular expression:

```
User.find({
    "username": new RegExp("hap")
}).exec(function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        next(err);
        return;
    }

    return res.json(results);
});
```

But this cannot be efficient, right? I mean, with a regular expression MongoDB basically touches all documents in the user collection or am I wrong? What is the best practice solution for such a search query?

Comment: I think this blog post could be useful as it has performance benchmark tests between [Full Text Search and Regular Expressions](https://comsysto.com/blog-post/mongodb-full-text-search-vs-regular-expressions)

Comment: Use MongoDB in conjunction with some kind of caching like redis cache. Run regex on cached meta data.

Answer (score 0):

Searching using regular expression is pretty efficient (at least for sql) unless you have wide array of characters included in your search (complex-random search) that out-limits your databases (regex's) capabilities or unless you have too many databases to search from that it takes forever for your regex to find them all in reasonable time. Specifically for mongoDB, I usually go with:

```
>db.collection.find( { key: { $regex: 'P.*'} } ).pretty();
```

This command should give me all details about 'key' starting with letter 'P'. Some people also use %"Your-Expression-Here%. However, I would suggest above command to be more efficient. Have a look at documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: What is the difference between your query and my regex query? My mongoose query above provides the following mongodb query: `users.find({ username: /hap/ }) { fields: undefined }`. The only difference I can see is that I search for all usernames containing the substring and you only want those starting with it.

Comment: I am not very sure as I cannot physically work out the solution. However look at this website: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/tutorial/model-data-for-keyword-search/

Comment: It indexes search before searching it (doesn't give an appropriate reason). Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

In context of your example, you won't be able to perform plain text search.

> The $text operator matches on the complete stemmed word. So if a
>   document field contains the word blueberry, a search on the term blue
>   will not match. However, blueberry or blueberries will match.

On the over hand, if you don't want to mess with regex. Give a try to where:

```
User.find().$where(function() {
    return this.username.indexOf('hap') != -1; 
});
```